# Discord.JS code won't understand member highest role with message.member role

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make discord.js ban command, make better like a role checking before the ban.

e.g. Administrator trying to ban another Administrator, but they're roles are same, this will give to bot signal and don't ban mentioned user, but the code just giving me always same message = Sorry, but the mentioned member have the higher role by position or you having the same role. (from russian)

```
            if(target == message.author) { 
                return message.channel.send('You can\'t ban yourself!');
            }
            if(message.member.roles.highest.position <= member.roles.highest.position) {
                return message.channel.send('Your role are same or the mentioned user is have higher role by position!');
            }

            if(target) {
                const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
                const duration = args.slice(1).join(' ')
                const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Причина не указана.';
                targetMember.ban(
                    { days: duration,
                      reason: `${reason}`}).catch(err => {
                          message.channel.send(`err ${err}`)
                      })
                if(target == message.author) {
                return message.channel.send('Вы не можете забанить себя!');
            }
            if(message.member.roles.highest.position <= member.roles.highest.position) {
                return message.channel.send('Ваша роли либо одинаковы или роль пользователя выше!');
            }

            if(target) {
                const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
                const duration = args.slice(1).join(' ')
                const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Причина не указана.';
                targetMember.ban(
                    { days: duration,
                      reason: `${reason}`}).catch(err => {
                          message.channel.send(`err ${err}`)
                      })
```

Comment: Your if statement is comparing `message.member.roles` with `member.roles` which looks to be the same member, should you be checking `target.member` instead?

Comment: Skully, do you mean to do: target.member.roles.highest.position instead member.roles.highest.position?

Comment: Yes, because you appear to be just checking the member who is executing the command against themselves, rather than checking the command executor with the target member from the @mention.

Comment: Well, after changing this line, code start giving me the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: const target = mentions.users.first();